# Jenkins JNLP slave FitNesse plug-in always trys to connect to localhost

Tags: linux, jenkins, jnlp, fitnesse

On a Linux system, I have configured a Jenkins master and slave to run a test suite through the FitNesse plugin.

The slave executes my job up to the point of standing up the FitNesse wiki.

However, Jenkins/Fitnesse plugin on the master cannot determine the host name of the slave running the FitNesse suite.

The command-line log shows:
Executing Fitnesse tests... on http://localhost
Failed ... in 30000 milliseconds.

How can I configure the job or slave so that the FitNesse plugin will try to execute the FitNesse tests on the proper host?  The slave is on a different host from the master.

Answer (score 0):

[This link image of configuring fitnesse plugin to jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aCpf.jpg)

When we install fitnesse-plugin to jenkins you would be seeing "Add Build Step" you would be seeing "Execute Fitnesse suite" link on that and configure as shown in the image above

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkins worker configuration, under "Node Properties" :

Add an Environment variable name=HOSTNAME value=my-worker-host-name

This fixes the problem.  I do not see the addition of the HOSTNAME environment variable documented, but without it the worker will not run.